# Objective-C - Delay open view iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uiviewcontroller

I have a map with markers (GoogleMaps framework 1.8.1 - iPhone 4S - iOS 7.1). Every time I click on a marker I need to show to another screen.

**The problem is that it has a delay 2-3 seconds on any screen that is connected to this view with map. In some instances the delay reaches 20 to 30 seconds.**

Code creation map:

```
camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                     longitude: locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
                                          zoom: 14];
map = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,
                                           0,
                                           self.view.frame.size.width,
                                           self.view.frame.size.height)
                                           camera: camera];
```

Code `didTapMarker`:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"EntityDetail" sender: self];
return YES;
```

*PS: This not only happens at the click of the markers. Happens on any screen that is connected to this with the map.*

Code `viewDidLoad` view controller segue:

```
NSString * titleString =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Title Here"];
    if (titleString.length > 15) {
        self.title = [titleString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 15)];
    }else{
        self.title = titleString;
    }
```

**Even though it only takes a screen this big delay.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and implementation found what was causing.

**Solution:**

When we add the Google Maps framework to our project it creates a reference to framework automatically in **Build Settings** on **Framework search paths**.
When we exclude the framework he does not remove automatically this reference.

Turns out I came across **references** the **old version** of the framework that was using. I **removed** this **reference** and it worked perfectly.