# Objective-C - Performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, core-location

**What is the performance impact of using GPS (CoreLocation)?**

I have this question for the following problem I am facing:

I'm developing an application, with google maps API, that display the current position of the device and other markers next to it. At the marker touch event, it will be forwarded to another screen. So far it's all right.

**The Problem:**
In all events that opens another screen (only from this screen with the map) there is a very long delay (reaching up to 1 minute) to proceed to the next screen. I've tried stop update the location but without success.

I have posted a question about this problem with code in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059470/objective-c-delay-open-view-ios-7-1)

- I am using an iPhone 4S;
- iOS 7.1.2;
- Google Maps (1.8.1);
- Xcode 5;

**I already tried using MKMapView. However the problem remains.**

***In devices such as iPhone 5 (simulator) and iPad (real device) this delay does not exist.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and implementation found what was causing.

**Solution:**

When we add the Google Maps framework to our project it creates a reference to framework automatically in **Build Settings** on **Framework search paths**.
When we exclude the framework he does not remove automatically this reference.

Turns out I came across **references** the **old version** of the framework that was using. I **removed** this **reference** and it worked perfectly.

Solution on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059470/objective-c-delay-open-view-ios-7-1)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have the same problems when i test googleMaps API. 
I look like apple use a other triangulation method then Google, so we have a lot of 
extra operations to calculate your position.
after same days of work i have switch to MKMapView.
The Info do search for you will find under the Object type [MKPlacemark](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mapkit/reference/MKPlacemark_Class/index.html)

Comment: Have try i with Wlan or with out Wlan?

Comment: I tried with and without (iPhone 4S and 5). On iPad only with.